# Android Speech Recognition NullPointer Exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, speech-recognition

I have made an android app which uses speech recognition. The problem is that it shows nullpointerexception.

The code which shows the error is :

```
public void startVoiceRecognitionActivity()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, getClass().getPackage().getName());
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Give Me An Order!");
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
    startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);
}
/**
 * Handle the results from the recognition activity.
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //store the result that the user might have said but google thinks he has said that only
        ArrayList<String> r=data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        String[] result = new String[r.size()];
        result = r.toArray(result);
        Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),search.class);
        if(result[0].length()<=0)
        {
            showToast("Could not fetch command properly try again");
        }
        else
        {
            i.putExtra("q", result[0]);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

the error is occurring on the line    `if(result[0].length()<=0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from the documentation of `<T> T[] toArray(T[] a)`:

> If the list fits in the specified array with room to spare (i.e., the
>   array has more elements than the list), the element in the array
>   immediately following the end of the list is set to null.

Thus if your `r` variable points to empty list the first element of your array will be `null`. This is causing your NPE. You can try verifying the size of the list, but it is most certainly the case.

Comment: thanks for the reply. see i published the app to android market and i saw this error. i tried two bugfixes but it failed. the main problem is that r is being returned null from the voice recognition engine. can you help me out a bit..?

Comment: @HimanshuJaju regretfully I have not worked with the voice recognition API, I can just point you to the cause of the current error you get.

Comment: btw if i have 10 things in the list and 11 can be stored in my array, then which one will be null..?